# Folium popup doesn't show when viewing html in Internet Explorer

Tags: python, internet-explorer, popup, geopandas, folium

HTML doesn't show in internet explorer when Folium Popups are included.

I've spent hours trying to get my HTML of a map showing in my browser with folium popups included (without them it works fine). After hours of trying to figure it out I decided to try opening the HTML on my phone instead (with google chrome) and it worked fine. So basically, I've concluded it is an issue with my internet explorer. Any ideas what is wrong or if there is an alternative way to show popups with Folium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figure our a pretty good solution.

So the problem is that back ticks (`) don't work with internet explorer, so I just replaced them with single quotes (') and now everything works fine.

I replaced them using:

```
with open(oldhtml) as inf:
        txt = inf.read()
        txt = txt.replace("`","'")

with open(newhtml, "w") as outf:
        outf.write(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you used F12 dev tools in IE to check if there's any error in console?

Besides, I think Folium itself may have compatibility issues with IE. Even the [official examples](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html) can't shown in IE. You could open the link in IE and you'll find the outcomes of samples are blank.

You could check [this post](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1107) to see if the backticks contained in the generated html for the `Popup` element avoids IE to render the map. But you could see the member of python-visualization said that ***`folium` and `leaflet` itself have some IE incompatibilities and there is no promise to work on that browser***. And in [this post](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/489), please also pay attention to that *IFrame with data uri as src attribute is not supported in IE*.